# MySQL2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column can't have a default value

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, alter-table, blob, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a rails mysql migration on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk.

It fails with this error message:

> Mysql2::Error: BLOB/TEXT column 'description' can't have a default value: ALTER TABLE `items` ADD `description` text DEFAULT ''

I found out from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466872/why-cant-a-text-column-have-a-default-value-in-mysql) thread that Amazon RDS might be in strict mode. How do I change the mode?

Answer (score 1):

> `BLOB`, `TEXT`, `GEOMETRY`, and `JSON` columns cannot be assigned a default value.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-type-defaults.html

What you are in essence asking -- without realizing it, presumably -- is how to force MySQL to revert to its old, incorrect behavior of ignoring your incorrect table definition and pretending that you really said `ALTER TABLE items ADD description text NOT NULL` *but with the default value missing* because that is the only alternative.  So you are left with a nonsensical table definition.

The new, correct behavior is indeed tied to the new recommended `@@SQL_MODE` defaults.  You're going to make trouble for yourself it your preferred solution is to unfix the server, rather than unbreak your table definition.

I understand that this is "working" for you now, but my point is that it is still in fact broken.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` should reveal that your declared default value is in fact not there on your current production server.

Comment: its a table definition that already exist and is already working in production. Just not on aws.

Comment: `ALTER TABLE ...` to make it 'correct'?